# VBA code needed to search specific text in PDF first then copy n number of characters from the start position

Tags: vba, pdf, automation, ms-word

I have requirement where I need to copy few text from pdf file after specific text search. The count of copied text is not fixed

For eg

'Specific Requirements' xxx xxxxxx xxxx xx xxxx,

Below code copies all the data after found is true. But I need till comma only. After specific Requirements count of characters till comma are not fixed. Any idea for the last line of the code

```
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Format = False
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Text = "Specific Requirements"
    .Execute
  End With
  If .Find.Found = True Then
   ActiveDocument.Range(Start:0,End:=Count of characters till comma). copy 
End If
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way of doing this is to use wildcards. The code below assumes you don't want to include the comma.

```
With ActiveDocument.Range
    With .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Format = False
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Text = "Specific Requirements*,"
    End With
    If .Find.Execute Then
        .MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
        .Copy
    End If
End With
```

EDIT: To copy from space after initial text just move the start of the range:

```
With ActiveDocument.Range
    With .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Format = False
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Text = "Specific Requirements*,"
    End With
    If .Find.Execute Then
        .MoveStart wdCharacter, 22
        .MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
        .Copy
    End If
End With
```

Comment: thanks man. Really appreciated I tried wild characters as well but couldn't get what I was looking for. I believe wdFindStop and if condition really made huge impact. However one more request is there any way I could get copy the data after the last space of SR till comma. However after pasting I am using VBA replace method at the moment. Again thanks 

Comment: @PritamSingh - see edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Selection.Find` is a good approach for you.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub demo()
    Dim iStart As Long, iEnd As Long
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Format = False
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .Text = "Specific Requirements"
        .Execute
        If .Found Then
            iStart = Selection.Range.Start
            With Selection.Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                .Format = False
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .MatchWildcards = False
                .Text = ","
                .Execute
                If .Found Then
'                    iEnd = Selection.Range.End ' include comma
                    iEnd = Selection.Range.Start ' NOT include comma
                    ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=iStart, End:=iEnd).Copy
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Microsoft reference document:

> [Selection.Find property (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.find?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: Hi taller_excelHome. Thanks really learnt something new. Thanks for the effort. One thing I believe Selection method only works with VBA Word and not with VBA Excel

Comment: You can utilize it with Excel VBA. The sole distinction is that you should qualify it with the Word application. For example, you can use `Set wdApp = GetObject(...)`, and then access its properties, such as `Debug.Print wdApp.Selection.Range.Start`.